# Calling "write" function of knockout computed

Tags: knockout.js

When I click on the .cloudChck check-box, the cloudClicked is called and I get JS error *"Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function"* I suppose it calls the read of the computed variable instead of write function. How do I call the write function ? Thanks !

```
<input name="serviceType" value="Cloud" type="checkbox" class="cloudChck" data-bind="checked: isCloud, click: cloudClicked">   
<input name="serviceType" value="Desktop" type="checkbox" class="desktopChck" data-bind="checked: isDesktop, click: desktopClicked">   

function AppViewModel() {
    ...
    this.isDesktop = ko.computed({
       read: function (){
            if (provinceId === "foo" || provinceId === 'bar') {
                return true;
            }
            else return this.isDesktop;
        },
        write: function (value){
            this.isDesktop = value;
        },
    }, this);

    this.cloudClicked = function () {
        if (this.isDesktop == true) {
            this.isDesktop(false);
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple problems wih this code...

`this.isDesktop` is being overwritten by `this.isDesktop = value;`

Computed observables are functions that are dependent on one or more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of these dependencies change.

You have to save the value of `this.isDesktop` to another observable.

Also...

```
this.cloudClicked = function () {
    if (this.isDesktop == true) { //call computeds as a function this.isDesktop()
        this.isDesktop(false);
    }
    return true;
};
```

You need to call `this.isDesktop()` to read from the computed observable.

I would check the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) on computed observables again...but dont give up, knockout is worth the learning curve!

Comment: What do you mean by "this.isDesktop is being overwritten by this.isDesktop = value;" ?

Comment: When you call `this.isDesktop = value`, `this.isDesktop` doesn't equal `ko.computed` anymore. It was overwritten with `value`. You are overwriting your computed observable from within your computed observable...